# Is it a bad practice to add large parts of HTML that's not required to be visible when the site loads using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have 2 popup modals in each HTML file to allow users to login and sign up, and was wondering if it was possible to simple have a common js file to add it using innerHTML or a similar method instead of typing it out in every HTML file. Would this cause any performance issues?

Comment: just use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse

Comment: It probably won't cause a performance issue. Your website will actually load faster this way

Comment: @bkr How can this tool help here?

Comment: @Tracer69 it measures your site  performance and indicates what can be improved. Exactly what he is asking. Its part of the chrome dev tools

Comment: @Tracer69 I see. Thank you

Comment: @bkr I did try lighthouse, but an issue I thought of was how it would work when the server has a heavy load. Because even using an entry server that hosts my frontend, backend and database (only doing this for testing purposes) I still get a 99% Thats why I thought if it would actually deteriorate the performance since its coming off javascript

Comment: @HishamBawa
for consumers switch device from desktop to mobile. If its green, no need to make it more complex

Comment: @bkr Ill keep that in mind. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Neither should cause major issues with performance, especially since you're not trying to show these models until the user has interacted with the page.

You're mentioning that you would have to copy-paste this HTML chunk into every file. This would violate the DRY principle, and cause you to be left maintaining copy-pasted HTML in many different files, which is never a good thing. In this scenario, I would go for dynamically generated HTML.

If you want to dynamically generate the HTML yourself (without a templating library, etc), then I would avoid .innerHTML as much as possible - it's convenient, but it's also easy to fall into [security pitfalls](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) with it. Prefer using the Javascript built-in DOM APIs.

I personally like to use this helper function to make the DOM APIs easier to use.

```js
function el(tagName, attrs = {}, children = []) {
  const newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(attrs)) {
    newElement.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
  newElement.append(...children);
  return newElement;
}

// USAGE

const customElement = el('div', { id: 'myId', class: 'myClass' }, [
  el('p', {}, ['Some Text']),
  el('br')
])

// The above element will get added to the body, and has the following shape:
// <div id="myId" class="myClass">
//   <p>Some Text</p>
//   <br>
// </div>

document.body.appendChild(customElement)
```

You certainly don't have to use it, do whatever floats your boat, but I just find that a helper function like that makes it easy to write HTML-looking Javascript code, without the temptation to actually use .innerHTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this function. The modals were required in every page, which made me think why not just add it dynamically using javascript. Initially I was planning on just having an empty `div` and adding the other content using `innetHTML` but after reading about it for a while, I understand that this is not recommended, so I'll try the method you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it. It won't affect the performance.

Comment: Phew. I'll use js to add them then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't effect performance. If anything, if the scripts loading is deferred it might improve the performance.

As for bad practice, I don't think it would be. I mean how is it any different to something like React that has a html file with a div with an id and injects the bundled react app (webpack js files) into

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks